# Unable to connect to Kafka from a Java app, but able from my machine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**My setup:**
So I just finished configuring a kafka instance, running on a `VM`, with the address: `192.168.0.100`. I can connect to that instance using `kafka-consome-consumer.sh` from the same VM and also from the `host` machine (outside the VM) using `kafkatool`.

[image]

**My problem:** I am now trying to produce messages to the instance using Java (using IntellijIDEA on the `host`), but the app is unable to connect. I am getting the following error:

```
Topic ABC not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here is my Kafka `server.properties` address config:

```
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.100:9092
```

And here is my producer code:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.0.100:9092");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put("retries", 0);

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("trucks_GPS", "Hello from a JAVA app");

        producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                if(e != null){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("success");
                }
            }
        });

        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
```

**The exact error log as requested**
`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic trucks_GPS not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: i think you need to use bridge network in case of vm, please check more about it

Comment: @silentsudo can I have a public IP using bridge mode?

Comment: what does your infrastructure looks like, local system local network, aws or azure or any random cloud platform, i still think this is networking issue try something similar to this https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-administration-and-monitoring-ui-tools\

Comment: @silentsudo As I mentioned in my post, I am already using kafkatool, and I can connect to my broker with no issues from another machine on the same network (home network). The issue is when I try to connect using the Java code I posted.

Comment: this much logs is not sufficient to investigate can you please add more finer logs>

Comment: @silentsudo I just added a screenshot of my kafkatool working + the exact exception am getting.. On the kafka side there are no errors, it's maily on my producer side.

Comment: Did you give the Zookeeper or Kafka address for the GUI/CLI tools? As mentioned, you'll need to port forward, or use a network bridge

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I gave the address to the GUI tool and it worked flawlessly. But when I put the exact same address:port in my code it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Which address? Zookeeper? 2) Can you use `kafkacat -L -b 192.168.0.100:9092` from the host? or the other console tools? 3) Are you able to use `AdminClient.descripeTopics` with your `trucks_GPS` topic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I am able to do all of that. and I can connect to the cluster using both the zookeeper or the broker ip. The only issue I have is with the java code.. I have no idea why I can't connect using it.